# Integral of $1/\cos^2 x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Usually, I say to students that

$\int \frac {1}{\cos^2 x}\,dx=\int \sec^2 x=\tan x +c$

based directly on the list of immediate integrals. The other day a student asked me if we can evaluate the integral using a method like integration by substitution or integration by parts. The only 'solution' I found uses the differentiation of quotient working backwards. I.e.

\begin{align*}
\int\frac {1}{\cos^2 x}\,dx&=\int\frac {\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}\,dx=\int\left (\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)'\,dx=\tan x+c
\end{align*}

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Without substitution nor by parts leaves you little options !

Comment: the given integral is on the list of the immediate ones

Comment: @YvesDaoust I apologize for the inconvenience. I wrote the question using my mobile phone. Without was used mistakenly.

Comment: Don't worry. Besides the immediate way, the decomposition of $1$ *is* quite elegant, IMO.

Comment: @tommik I know. That is what I said to students. But somebody asked me how we can evaluate this integral without using tables of antiderivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the identity

$$\sec^2(x)=\tan^2(x)+1$$ you can attempt the change of variable $u=\tan(x)$ or $x=\arctan(u)$. This turns the integral to

$$\int\frac{u^2+1}{u^2+1}du.$$

Comment: One can justify the method after the fact by saying that the substitution will rationalize the expression, which is polynomial in $\tan(x)$. Indeed, the expression gets rationalized *to death*.